# Verifying Frequency Probability in Octave

Tags: probability, computer-science

I asked [a question in stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244195/frequency-of-n-independent-events) pertaining to the frequency of $N$ events that have weighted outcomes.

I'm doing my own embedded implementation, and would like to check my work. How would I do this in octave? I want to check for the case where $N=15$ using the random events below:

\begin{align*}
f_1(0.870292482885583,15)\\
f_2(0.296072459472033,9)\\
f_3(0.239476668131953,6)\\
f_4(0.210507137319701,18)\\
f_5(0.385627406961031,11)\\
f_6(0.340338025468699,10)\\
f_7(0.488128489957119,11)\\
f_8(0.983321258332711,18)\\
f_9(0.092710364886216,11)\\
f_{10}(0.993127281732787,9)\\
f_{11}(0.206742439976538,16)\\
f_{12}(0.0678548007254048,9)\\
f_{13}(0.74522192081138,8)\\
f_{14}(0.114650275403596,15)\\
f_{15}(0.804419665265864,5)\\
\end{align*}

The weights sum to 171. I've run my own implementation and learned that there is a roughly $30\%$ chance that the sum of the weights is greater than or equal to 86.

How do I reach that same conclusion in octave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do a Monte Carlo simulation of the problem:

```
%%first define N and the probability and weight vectors p,w
k = 1000; %number of simulations to run
sums = sum(double(rand(k,N)<p(:)') * w(:), 2); %sum for each simulation
p_success = mean(sums >= 86); %empirical frequency of the sum being (e.g.) at least 86
```